# How to convert list.files() output to an int?

Tags: r, if-statement, control-structure

The output when checking an empty directory with R's `list.files()` is a character string...

```
> list.files('/home/someDir')
character(0)
```

But I would like to test its length and use it in a control structure like

```
> current <- '/home/someDir'
> dirPick <- function(){
    tryCatch(
      if (length(list.files(current) > 0)) {
        dirData <- current
      } else {
        dirData <- old
      }
    )
  }
```

But the object returned by `list.files()` doesn't act like I'd expect:

```
> list.files('/home/someDir') == 0
logical(0)


> as.numeric(list.files('/home/someDir')) == 0
logical(0)
```

Not sure I understand the difference between a logical and boolean, but why doesn't this just act like an integer zero?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
length(list.files('/home/someDir')) == 0
```

The value `character(0)` indicates some like an empty variable. Thats why you can't sum or convert it into 0 without `length()` attribute

Comment: Or `!length(...)` though that may be less readable.